# implementing Unittest for property decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I've got this code that gathers the first name of a person.

```
class Person:

   #initializing the variables and giving them an empty string as a baseline.
    def __init__(self, first_name = '', last_name = ''):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name


    @property
    #getting first name and returning it for future use.
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name
    

    #setting the first name
    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, first_name):
        #capitalizing the first name.
        self._first_name = first_name.capitalize()


    @property
    #getting last name and returning it for future use.
    def last_name(self):
        return  self._last_name


    @last_name.setter
    #setting last name
    def last_name(self, last_name):
        #capitalizing last name    
        self._last_name = last_name.capitalize()
```

and I want to create a unittest that tests the class/first_name/property decorator, and I wanted to see if I was going about it the right way?

```
import unittest
from person import Person
class TestPerson(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first_name(self):
        Person._first_name = first_name('FakeName')
        self.assertEqual(Person._first_name(), 'FakeName')

    #updated code to fix errors pointed out. The first name works!
    #the last name does not.
    def test_last_name(self):
        testLast = Person('LastName')
        #Throws assertion error '' != 'LastName here. 
        self.assertEqual(testLast.last_name, 'LastName')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The unittest coding runs and passes without error, but I was wondering if it was using the property decorator at all? I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to decorators and unittesting, so I wanted to make sure this was actually using the property decorator rather than bypassing it, or if I should be formatting it some other way(or using unittest.mock, as a few other forums have suggested, but I'm not familiar with .mock at all).

EDIT: Because I was totally smart at 3 in the morning, I completely bypassed actually setting a class that inherits from unittest. This has been adjusted in the second code clip. Also added my last_name to the Person and unittest for more information on how the two should be interacting.

EDIT 2: All code has been adjusted to the edits suggested. Thank you everyone! Will continue to slowly fix my errors haha.

Comment: Your code doesn't look valid. Where is `first_name` defined? Why is `self` passed to `test_first_name`? That's really odd. Normally with `unittest` you derive from a `Test` class or similar.

Comment: Your setters must decorate a method that is named after the attribute you are trying to control. If I do `Person('foo')`, it raises an error, because `self._first_name = first_name` is trying to set an attribute that is not settable, because you defined no setter for it! `@_first_name.setter` must decorate `def _first_name(...)` for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's fix the class before you worry about testing it.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first_name=''):
        self.first_name = first_name

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name
    
    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, first_name):
        self._first_name = first_name.capitalize()

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return  self._last_name

    @last_name.setter
    def last_name(self, last_name):
        #capitalizing last name    
        self._last_name = last_name.capitalize()
```

Only the getter and setter interact directly with the `_first_name` attribute, and the property name itself should be part of the public interface (i.e., *not* prefixed with a `_`). (Note that the property and the backing attribute cannot share the same name.)

Now, the test:

```
import unittest
from person import Person

class TestPerson(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first_name(self):
        p = Person('fakeName')
        self.assertEqual(p.first_name, 'FakeName')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

You need to create an instance of `Person`, then check that the value returned by the property matches the expected name. For this example, I passed a non-capitalized name to `Person` to check that the setter capitalizes it as expected.

Also, the test method must be an instance method of (a subclass of) `unittest.TestCase` for `unittest.main` to find and run it. `main` looks for appropriately named classes, instantiates them, then runs appropriately named methods with those instances.

Comment: Oops! Yes, thanks for pointing out the errors. I wrote this at 3 am and half asleep haha. Edited these errors to be corrected in my program and went along with your recommendation, but it returned:
```self.first_name = first_name
 AttributeError 'can't set attribute 'first_name'. ```
and I know I simplified this for stackoverflows sake, but would the syntax of ```p = Person('FakeName')``` be the same if I had a first_name and last_name initialized in Person, or should I be calling the separate functions as well?

Comment: Now you have changed your code, the unittest can be changed to include a second parameter of last_name, but it’s ok as is since it has a default.

Comment: "and the property name itself should be part of the public interface " I disagree that it *has* to be.

Comment: Also, this is wrong, `@first_name.setter` must decorate a method with the name of the attribute you are trying to control, so not `def set_first_name` but `def first_name`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wouldn't changing the ```set_first_name``` to ```def first_name``` affect the property getter since it's listed by the same name?

Comment: @SlipScout **the getter and setter are contained in the same `property` object**. Using the decorator `@` syntax is just a convenience, the other way would be to define *two differently named methods*, e.g. `def get_first_name` and `def set_first_name` then doing `first_name = property(get_first_name, set_first_name)`, but if you *do* use the `@` syntax they *must* have the same name! Otherwise you have *two different properties!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh!!! I see. After editing the code properly and running it, it does work for the first name! The downside is that I can't seem to get it to work for the last name. Says ``` self.assertEqual(testLast.last_name, 'LastName')``` has an ```AssertionError: '' != 'LastName')```. Will continue hopping back and forth to see if I can get it to work. Updated code is in og posting.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I forgot to change that.

Comment: Basically, `first_name.setter` isn't magic; it just creates a *new* property with the same methods as the original, but with the decorated function as the new setter, then it binds that new property to the name of the decorated function.

Comment: @SlipScout Regarding the last name, you used the name of the *instance attribute*, rather than the name of the property, with the setter decorator.

Comment: @chepner oops, yes, just saw that. It had been fixed in my running code, I just missed it when copying it over. Any ideas on how to get the test_last_name to work? I know with Person('Name') it just keeps assigning the first name, not assigning a last name which is why its failing, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what the proper solution to that is. Everything I've tried has gone kaput.

Comment: The exact same way you set the first name: pass an argument to `__init__`, and assign the value to the property. You changed the definition of `Person`, but did not change how you instantiate the class in the test method to match.